# Behaviour of fseek with SEEK_END and a positive offset?

Tags: c, fseek

Lets say we have a file "x" containing the string "0123456789".

We open the file and have a file descriptor `fd`.

We can do `read(fd, some_buffer, 5)` to read 5 values into the buffer from the file.

Similarly, we can use fseek to move the pointer to the individual entries in the file.

My question is, what is the behavior of `fseek` when we used `SEEK_END` with a positive offset? Is this behavior undefined, or does it wrap around to the front of the contents of the file?

So if we did `fseek(fd, 5, SEEK_END)`, where would the pointer be pointing to now?

Comment: As far as the C specification is concerned, SEEK_END need not be supported for binary files, and is definitely not supported for text files. One thing is certain: SEEK_END with a positive offset will not wrap around to the front of the file. It'll either enlarge the file, or fail.

Answer (score 4):

> My question is, what is the behavior of `fseek` when we used `SEEK_END`
>   with a positive offset? Is this behavior undefined, or does it wrap
>   around to the front of the contents of the file?

If the stream is a *text* stream then as far as the C language is concerned, the behavior is undefined, because the standard specfies that:

> For a text stream, either `offset` shall be zero, or `offset` shall be
>   a value returned by an earlier successful call to the `ftell` function
>   on a stream associated with the same file and `whence` shall be
>   `SEEK_SET`.

([C2011, 7.21.9.2/4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.2p4)).  No behavior is defined for the combination of a nonzero offset and `SEEK_END`.

For a binary stream,

> the new position, measured in characters from the beginning of the
>   file, is obtained by adding offset to the position specified by
>   `whence`

([C2011, 7.21.9.2/3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.2p3)), so no, it absolutely does not wrap around.  The standard goes on to say that

> A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a
>   whence value of `SEEK_END`

, so such a call as you describe may (definedly) just fail, returning an error code.  If it does succeed, however -- and with some implementations it can be expected to do so for some streams -- then it results in the file position being past the end of the file.  Attempts to read at such a position should have the same result as if the position was at EOF.  Attempts to write have behavior that are dependent on the open mode of the file (all writes to streams opened in append mode go to the current end of the file) and on the implementation.

On a POSIX system, for example, the system's C implementation is specified to allow positioning streams associated with regular files past the end of the file, and successfully writing at such a position has behavior as if bytes with value 0 were written into all positions between that and the previous end of the file.  Furthermore, POSIX does not make any distinction in practice between text and binary streams.

Answer (score 0):

Why not read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fseek)?

> POSIX allows seeking beyond the existing end of file. If an output is
>   performed after this seek, any read from the gap will return zero
>   bytes. Where supported by the filesystem, this creates a sparse file.